# Bootstrap error: this._config is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I have the following button:

```html
<button class="kv_styleclass_0 btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" 
    data-bs-toggle="modal" 
    data-bs-target="formModal" 
    type="button">
        Стать участником
</button>
```

that triggers the following modal dialog:

```html
<div class="modal fade" 
    aria-labelledby="formModal_label" 
    aria-hidden="true" 
    id="formModal" 
    tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" 
                        id="formModal_label">
                            Анкета участника
                    </h5>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-primary" 
                        data-bs-dismiss="modal" 
                        type="button">
                            Закрыть
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe src="..." 
                        name="..." 
                        style="height: 407px;" 
                        width="650" 
                        frameborder="0">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click the button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._config is undefined
    _initializeBackDrop bootstrap.esm.js:2916
    ...
```

Using NPM to get Bootstrap. Using Bootstrap v5.2.3.

I tried to get Bootstrap JS by including the `<script>` tag in my code in different positions. With Popper.JS.

Comment: Try `data-bs-target="#formModal"` (#).

Comment: Yeah! Thanks! I missed the "#". You can post the answer if you want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just had the same issue and I solved it by adding a # to the data-bs-target. This is what the modified code would look like:

```
<button class="kv_styleclass_0 btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" 
    data-bs-toggle="modal" 
    data-bs-target="#formModal" 
    type="button">
        Стать участником
</button>
```

It looks like you are passing in a string while the data-bs-target attribute expects an id.

EDIT: I just saw that CodeCaster beat me to it in a comment. Oops!

Answer (score -1):

```html
<button class="kv_styleclass_0 btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" 
  data-bs-target="formModal" 
  type="button">
    Стать участником
</button>
```

In your button tag, you have to remove this attribute: `data-bs-toggle="modal"`. Then run your application; it will resolve the problem.

Comment: I didnt remove data-bs-toggle. i just changed it to data-toggle and it worked. ("i removed the 'bs')